# Preventing Android variable from hacking

Tags: android, security

Now I want to make an online contest for my Android application.

The problem is that I'm sure whether they will hack their scores, which would ruin my contest.

There are lots of ways to change the score variable, with programs like Root Explorer and gameC: what should I do?

I have some ideas, like using SHA1, but I think it is still possible to hack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the stored variable in your app a fake value that needs to be modified(Don't worry i'll explain).let's say you have  `int Score` if the player scored a point `add 2` instead of `1`. Now your `integer` its `double` what it should be.Now when you display the `Score` you should for example do this `tv1 = Score/2` now if he used a cheat engine searching for let's say number `2` he wouldn't find anything useful since the int is actually `= 4`

P.S:this is not a 100% effective way.Actually there is always a way to hack an application you can only make it extremely difficult.

Answer (score -1):

Use ProGuard:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

For a more general overview of the best practices regarding security, check out this:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/index.html

Comment: Adding proguard support indeed makes it difficult to *reverse engineer*, but it will not prevent it and for simple cases it even fails to deter the attacker from getting the correct variable. Once the name is found, it could be changed using reflection or other cracking methods.